# Backup latest ubuntu server

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, backup

I need to copy a drive from remote host. I can't do it just with scp, maybe there are some workarounds and solutions for this?
Operating system is ubuntu 20.04
If you need more information, please ask me for more information.
I have searched on Google but doesn't work...
I am very thanks for you.

Comment: What from the drive do you need to copy? What can't you do it just with `scp`, specifically? What are the details of the remote host—is it a VPS, or something similar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: See `man rsync`, it's a good start.

Comment: no, i need full copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a full filesystem from a remote host, you can use the command:

```sh
ssh user@hostname 'sudo tar -cJf - --acls --selinux --one-file-system /' > full_dump.tar.xz
```

Then just unzip `tar.xz` into the current directory. To do this, use something like this:

```sh
tar xf linux_full_dump.tar.xz
```